# Multiply coefficients with different weights

Tags: weights

I have two models with different weights (0.97, 0.11).

Table of models and coefficients:

[image]

Currently, I compute the final prediction using:
$Prediction_{Final} = (Prediction_{Model1} * Weight_{Model1}) + (Prediction_{Model2} * Weight_{Model2})$

$<=> 0.2086 = (0.13 * 0.97) + (0.75* 0.11)$

However, I would like to compute the same result (0.2086) using two final coefficients (see ? in the table), like this:
$Prediction_{Final} = Coef1_{FinalCoefficient} * Coef2_{FinalCoefficient}$

How can I compute the final coefficients so that I take into account the different weights of the models?

Sidenote:

- Coef1 could be also interpreted as intercept.
- There could be more than only two coefficients.